# What should the order of sections be in a formal report?

Tags: academic-writing

How should I order the following sections in a formal report?

- Glossary
- Bibliography
- References
- Appendix

Answer (score 1):

The References section follows the Appendix section.

The Glossary is an optional element of the Appendix Section.

And the Bibliography is the last part of the References.

You can also look at other formal reports written at your institution for examples of ordering and style requirements.